# Google Line chart join two data table

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, charts, google-visualization

I want to generate two lines into one chart, so i using join method in google chart.
I can retrieve data from SQL, but the script mentioned the data in data table is not array.

I tried to use $.parseJSON but still cannot plot to chart.

anyone can give me some hint?

Thank you in advance.

here is my script:

```
    function drawMultiCavitiesChart() {
        var options = {
            title: 'Mulit Cavities vs Line',
            width: 1800,
            height: 700,
            //bar: { groupWidth: "95%" },
            //curveType: 'function',
            //isStacked: true
            pointSize: 8,
            hAxis: { title: 'Date', format: 'M/d/yy' },
            vAxis: { title: 'Total Cavities' },
            //colors: ['blue'],
            legend: { position: "bottom" }
        };

        var jsonData1 =
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Chart.aspx/GetMultiCavitiesData1",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (jsonData1) {

                console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonData1));
            },

        });
        //var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData1);
        //var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable($.parseJSON(jsonData1));

        var jsonData2 = 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Chart.aspx/GetMultiCavitiesData2",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (jsonData2) {
                
                console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonData2));
            },

        });
        //var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData2);

        var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable($.parseJSON(jsonData1));
        var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable($.parseJSON(jsonData2));

        //var joinedData = new google.visualization.data.join(data1, data2, 'full', [[0, 0], [1, 1]], [2], [2]);
        var joinedData = new google.visualization.data.join(data1, data2, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart($("#divMultiCavitiesChart")[0]);
        chart.draw(joinedData, options);          
    }
```

and the console:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax` runs asynchronously.
which means the lines of code after the `$.ajax` call,
will run before the `$.ajax` call has finished.

so you're trying to create the data tables, before the data has been received.

you need to wait for the `done` callback, before continuing to the next step.
(you can also use `success` as in your post, but that is old and deprecated)

try something similar to the following...

```
function drawMultiCavitiesChart() {

    var data1;
    var data2;

    var options = {
        title: 'Mulit Cavities vs Line',
        width: 1800,
        height: 700,
        //bar: { groupWidth: "95%" },
        //curveType: 'function',
        //isStacked: true
        pointSize: 8,
        hAxis: { title: 'Date', format: 'M/d/yy' },
        vAxis: { title: 'Total Cavities' },
        //colors: ['blue'],
        legend: { position: "bottom" }
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Chart.aspx/GetMultiCavitiesData1",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
    }).done(function (r1) {
      data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r1.d);

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "Chart.aspx/GetMultiCavitiesData2",
          data: '{}',
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
      }).done(function (r2) {
        data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r2.d);

        var joinedData = new google.visualization.data.join(data1, data2, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart($("#divMultiCavitiesChart")[0]);
        chart.draw(joinedData, options);
      });
    });
}
```